# Recursive Asynchronous calls with TPL/ async await

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, recursion

I am looking at processing a hierarchical structure in a recursive fashion using C# asynchronous features (TPL/ async/await). Here is an overview of what I am trying to do

I have a jobs collection to process as shown below. Each Job has something to do and optionally can have one or more children which also have something to do. All the parent and child jobs call the same function to do the actual "work" and this function in "asynchronous" (code below)

```
/*
 *  Jobs Collection
 *  |
 *  |__ Job1
 *  |    |__ Job4
 *  |    |     |__ Job7
 *  |    |
 *  |    |__ Job5
 *  |
 *  |__ Job2
 *  |    |__ Job6
 *  |
 *  |__ Job3
 *  |
 */
```

1. There are 3 levels in the hierarchy.
2. I would want to start processing the first level (Job1, Job2, Job3) in parallel.
3. Once they start in parallel, each individual job will start processing
   itself, wait for its processing to complete (important) and then will go on to process its children recursively until the hierarchy ends. Children are dependent on the data processed by the parent and hence they wait for parent processing to complete.
4. Processing of the actual "Job" (called by parent and children) happens asynchronously as the calling method works asynchronously - therefore a "new thread" is not required (Task.StartNew()).

Here is the sample code that I am using to demonstrate the scenario -

```
public void Process()
{
    WebJob[] jobs = CreateWebJobs(); // dummy jobs

    // first level 
    Parallel.ForEach(jobs,
                new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 2 }, // parallelism hardcoded for simplicity
                (job) => ExecuteJob(job));
}

private void ExecuteJob(WebJob job, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
    Console.WriteLine("Caller> {0} :: {1} Job> {2} :: {3} Thread> {4}", memberName, "\t", job.Name, "\t", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    Task t = GetDataAsync(job);
    t.Wait(); // needed such that parent response is received before children start over (?).


    if (job.Children != null)
    {
        job.Children.ToList().ForEach((r) =>
        {
            r.ParentResponse = job.Response; // Children need parent's response
            ExecuteJob(r);
        });
    }
}

private async Task GetDataAsync(WebJob j)
{
    // This is just test code. Ideally it would be an external call to some "async" method
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    j.Response = string.Format("{0} complete", j.Name);
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Cyan;
    Console.WriteLine("parentResp>> {0} :: {1} Job>> {2} :: {3} Thread>> {4}", j.ParentResponse, "\t", j.Name, "\t", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    Console.WriteLine("--------------");
}

private WebJob[] CreateWebJobs()
{
    return new WebJob[] {
        new WebJob() { Id=1, Name = "Job1", ExecURL = "http://url1", 
            Children = new WebJob[] 
            {
                new WebJob() 
                { 
                    Id=2, Name = "Job2", ExecURL = "http://url2", 
                    Children = new WebJob[] 
                    {
                        new WebJob() { Id=4, Name = "Job4", ExecURL = "http://url4" }
                    }
                },
                new WebJob() 
                { 
                    Id=3, Name = "Job3", ExecURL = "http://url3" 
                }
            }
        },
        new WebJob() { Id=5, Name = "Job5", ExecURL = "http://url5"}                
    };
}
```

- The Process Method starts of by launching all "first level" jobs in
  parallel.
- ExecuteJob Method takes over and recursively goes over to
  children to complete all processing

This works ok, but I am not convinced if this recursive async pattern is an efficient approach. I was thinking to avoid t.Wait(). I have tried ContinueWith on t which appears no different in my understanding, I also read about ForEachAsync pattern and was wondering if that would be a fit. This solution would eventually be an ASP.NET Web API service. Any thoughts on this recursive async pattern?

Comment: You've got Job5 in there twice. Does that mean it is dependent on 1 and 4 or is that a typo?

Comment: @mike - that was a typo. Corrected. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `GetDataAsync` is the only blocking operation that you have, then you can use asynchronous programming throughout, avoiding the need for `Parallel.ForEach` calls or blocking `Wait` calls.

```
public async Task Process()
{
    WebJob[] jobs = CreateWebJobs(); // dummy jobs

    await Task.WhenAll(jobs.Select(ExecuteJob));
}

private async Task ExecuteJob(WebJob job, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{
    Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
    Console.WriteLine("Caller> {0} :: {1} Job> {2} :: {3} Thread> {4}", memberName, "\t", job.Name, "\t", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

    await GetDataAsync(job);

    if (job.Children != null)
    {
        var childTasks = job.Children.Select(r =>
        {
            r.ParentResponse = job.Response;
            return ExecuteJob(r);
        });

        await Task.WhenAll(childTasks);
    }
}
```

**Edit**: If the top-level method should block (rather than risk having consumers fire-and-forget), do:

```
public void Process()
{
    WebJob[] jobs = CreateWebJobs(); // dummy jobs

    Task.WaitAll(jobs.Select(ExecuteJob));
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `Process` have the be `async` since you use `await` in it?

Comment: @juharr: Correct. Someone needs to `await` eventually, so I could either leave it to whoever calls `Process`, or else just block myself with a `Wait`

Comment: @Douglas - Makes sense and thanks for your thoughts. I am wondering if you'd ever want to use "Parallel.ForEach" to start off at least the first set of jobs. Let's say if I have to pre-process data before GetDataAsync can handle it. This might delay processing as it would be sequential until the pre-processing is complete (assuming it takes quite a few cpu cyles) and it gets to "GetDataAsync" method?

Comment: @Lalman: You raise a valid scenario. Unfortunately, `Parallel.ForEach` does not play nicely with `async`. The simplest solution would be to perform your preprocessing in its own task (at the beginning of `ExecuteJob`) and await its result: `await Task.Run(() => Preprocess(job))`. However, this does not allow the equivalent of a `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` (unless you define your own task scheduler).

Answer (score 2):

Since your core is asynchronous, you shouldn't be using parallel or multithreading at all. What you want is *concurrency* without *parallelism* - that is, asynchronous concurrency, usually done with `Task.WhenAll`.

This is doubly true since you're planning to deploy to ASP.NET, where parallelism can significantly reduce your scalability.

```
public async Task ProcessAsync()
{
  WebJob[] jobs = CreateWebJobs();

  await Task.WhenAll(jobs.Select(x => ExecuteJobAsync(x)));
}

private async Task ExecuteJobAsync(WebJob job, [CallerMemberName] string memberName = "")
{
  Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.DarkYellow;
  Console.WriteLine("Caller> {0} :: {1} Job> {2} :: {3} Thread> {4}", memberName, "\t", job.Name, "\t", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);

  await GetDataAsync(job);
  if (job.Children != null)
  {
    var childTasks = job.Children.Select(async x =>
    {
      x.ParentResponse = job.Response; // Children need parent's response
      await ExecuteJobAsync(x);
    });
    await Task.WhenAll(childTasks);
  }
}
```

Comment: Indeed... Just glanced at method signature instead of carefully looking at actual code. deleting comments .10...9...